# Extract multiple regex matches from same line in PIG

Tags: regex, apache-pig

This is what I want to do

```
INPUT 

    1,code=1a_asdfasdf_code=1b,asdf
    2,code=2a_asdfasdf_code=2b_code=2c_laksjdf;lksjdf,asdf
    3,code=3a_,sdoliclwmd

Intermediate 

    1,{1a,1b}
    2,{2a,2b,2c}
    3,{3a}


Finally
    1,1a
    1,1b
    2,2a
    2,2b
```

I know of REGEX_EXTRACT and REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL, but none of them gives  multiple matches for the same regex.

```
2,2c
3,3a
```

This is giving me only the first match

```
A = LOAD '/data/regsearch1.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (c1:chararray,c2:chararray,c3:chararray);

B = foreach A  generate c1,REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(c2,'.*code=([^_]+)_.*') as m1;
```

Comment: what's with the tag spam?

Comment: @roippi Copy paste error. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just FYI this question was about PIG-latin.

I ended up writing python UDF

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re;

@outputSchema("bag1:bag{tuple1:tuple(match:chararray)}")
def findallregex(pattern,str):
        outbag = []
        matches =  re.findall(pattern,str);
        for m in matches:
                tuple1 = (m,)
                outbag.append(tuple1);
        return outbag;
```

And then this PIG latin code

```
REGISTER '/findall.py' using org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myfuncs;
A = LOAD '/regsearch1.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (c1:chararray,c2:chararray,c3:chararray);
B = foreach A generate c1, myfuncs.findallregex('code=([^_]+)',c2) as bag1;
C = foreach B generate c1, flatten(bag1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use groups, i don't know if you need process that a lot but you can pull the first digit and process the pattern of your string.

```
input
    1,code=1a_asdfasdf_code=1b,asdf
    2,code=2a_asdfasdf_code=2b_code=2c_laksjdf;lksjdf,asdf
    3,code=3a_,sdoliclwmd 

output

    1,1a
    1,1b
    2,2a
    2,2b
    2,2c
    3,3a

private static void lineProcess(String text) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("code=(\\w\\w)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text); 
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(text.substring(0,1)+","+m.group(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: By default the dot (`.`) matches all characters except newlines. The `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier allows the dot to match newlines. When you write a pattern that doesn't use the dot, using this modifier is useless.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by simple string manipulation.

```
    A = LOAD 'Data.txt' Using PigStorage(',') AS (a1:int,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);
    B = foreach A generate a1, REPLACE(a2,'asdfasdf_','') AS a2;
    C = FOREACH B GENERATE a1, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(a2, '_')) AS parameter;
    D = FILTER C BY INDEXOF(parameter, 'code=') != -1;
    E = FOREACH D GENERATE a1, SUBSTRING(parameter, 5, 7) AS number;`
```